# Configuring Stylelint for VSCode Globally

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, stylelint

### Here's what I want to achieve: I want to configure the extension so that it checks and fixes automatically any errors in any .scss file that I create.

I don't want to install the packages manually for every project that I create.

### Here's what I've done so far:

- Installed StyleLint Extension
- Disabled VS Code's Built-In Linters
- Installed the following packages globally:

  - Postcss
  - Postcss-scss
  - stylelint
  - stylelint-config-recess-order
  - stylelint-order
- [Enabled SCSS validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsSqZ.png)
- [Added path to postcss syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK0fy.png)

Any advice on what to do next?